# Why mimeType when given "application/json" is not showing in the server backend?

Tags: c#, php, unity-game-engine

I am trying to upload a file into the server which is a .json file.I am sending the Binary data along with file name and Mimetype but in the backend it does not show which file extension it is.

How does this thing work?What happens if I have same filename but different extensions to upload into the server.Wht will happen if I want to upload and later deserialize it as two different extensions?

```
IEnumerator UploadFileData()
{
    string mapnamedl = "123";
    Debug.Log("Mapname local = " + mapnamedl);
    string locapath = "file://" + Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + mapnamedl + ".json";
    Debug.Log("local path = " + locapath);
    WWW localFile = new WWW(locapath);
    yield return localFile;

    if (localFile.error == null)
    {
        Debug.Log("Local file found successfully");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Open file error: " + localFile.error);
        yield break; // stop the coroutine here
    }

    Debug.Log("local file text" + localFile.text);
    WWWForm postForm = new WWWForm();
    string mimetypes = "application/json";
    postForm.AddBinaryData("Jsondata", localFile.bytes, mapnamedl, mimetypes);

    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("https://test.com/car/hariupload/save.php", postForm);
    yield return www.SendWebRequest();

    if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
    {
        Debug.Log(www.error);
    }
    else
    {
        string JSONDATAstring = www.downloadHandler.text;
        Debug.Log("Json String is = " + JSONDATAstring);
        JSONNode JNode = SimpleJSON.JSON.Parse(JSONDATAstring);

        string login = (JNode["upload"][0]["success"]).ToString();

        Debug.Log("login is = " + login);

        if (login == "1")
        {
            Debug.Log("Form upload complete!");
        }
        else if (login == "0")
        {
            Debug.Log("Failed ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try seeing what is actually sent via **Wireshark** or some other sniffing utility. Try using [`HttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8) (.NET 4.0+, or [`WebClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient) for below) to send your requests instead of Unity's libraries.

Comment: @AgentFire The file gets uploaded without any extensions.

Comment: Yeah, but how can you be so sure?

Comment: @AgentFire I convert it to binary and send...so it will be a binary file that gets saved there right?...Is there a way to upload the file directly with extension rather than converting it to binary and send.

Comment: There is, I just suggested you looking into the native .NET classes which are capable of doing just that.

Comment: You should make the PHP that handles the upload rename it to whatever it needs to be named. I guess this has more to do with PHP than Unity.

Answer (score 0):

+if you have binary (non-alphanumeric) data (or a significantly sized payload) to transmit, use multipart/form-data. Otherwise, use application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

-if you have to send non-ASCII text or large binary data, the form-data is for that.

You can use Raw if you want to send plain text or JSON or any other kind of string. Like the name suggests, Postman sends your raw string data as it is without modifications. The type of data that you are sending can be set by using the content-type header from the drop down.

Binary can be used when you want to attach non-textual data to the request, e.g. a video/audio file, images, or any other binary data file.

more details on : [documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1)